# How to inject HazelCast Map dependency to QueueStore

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast Queue store in which some computation needs to be done and after that computation I want to put the data in Hazelcast Map.
I am using Spring as IOC Container.

The problem is the QueueStore is not aware of HazelCast Instance and to get access to the Map I need hazelCast Instance. I tried doing a setter injection but it gives me a circular dependency error.

```
<hz:queue name="ProductQueue">
                <hz:queue-store enabled="true" store-implementation="productQueueStore"></hz:queue-store>
            </hz:queue>

<bean id="productQueueStore"
    class="com.csg.ib.fid.crd.etrading.prpl.hazelcast.queuestores.ProductQueueStore"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="inst" ref="hazelcastClusterInstance"> 
    </property> 
    </bean>
```

Also I tried creating a Factory class and tried to inject the property via factory-bean, factory-method approach but still it gives me a circular dependency error.

Any way I can make my QueueStore aware of the Hazelcast instance?
or 
Any way I can inject HazelCastClusterInstance in my QueueStore?
or
Any way I can inject IMap refernce in to my QueueStore.(i.e. hazelcastClusterInstance.getMap("Abc")?

Answer (score 1):

This could be very dangerous because there are constraints on what you can do on a queue store thread. If you are using an IMap and randomly hit partitions, probably this will be detected and you get exceptions in your face.

So I think you need to reconsider the current design.

Comment: What I wanted to do in QueueStore Thread was to persist an Object ,get the primary key identifier after persisting and then push that Object with "primaryKey"(retrieved after persisitng) as Key of Map and Object as Value of Map.  Could you please explain what is meant by  "If you are using an IMap and randomly hit partitions, probably this will be detected and you get exceptions in your face."

Comment: Is accessing a Map in Queue Store not allowed ? Why and how can it cause problem ?Also what are the restrictions on stuff I can do in QueueStore Thread that you are talking about ?

Comment: I actually tried to insert into IMap from QueueStore.Got the following Exception. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread[hz._hzInstance_1_prpl-Local.partition-operation.thread-1,5,_hzInstance_1_prpl-Local] cannot make remote call: PutOperation{Product} .Will think of some other way to achieve what I want

Comment: That is the exception I was warning about. What you could do is to put it in a queue (so not yet persisted to db), then have one or more threads take it from the queue and persist it in the db; then an id is generated. And after that is done the same thread puts it in an IMap

Comment: I created an executor and executed the task on it.Was able to modify the Map using this approach. I am currently making my queue store as ApplicationContextAware so that I can get hazelcastinstance bean from spring context.Any other elegant way by which my queueStore bean knows about hazelcastinstance.How can I injected hazelcastinstance in queue store bean?

Comment: I only know a hacky way. In the Hazelcast Config you define you QueueStore implementation by setting it on the QueueConfig. 

Once the HazelcastInstance is created, you set the HazelcastInstance on the QueueStore instance you have created.

It is extremely hacky and I don't like it because you will have a partially initialized data-structure for some time.